# Getting type of element inside of a matrix field using plugin hook

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, php, elementtype

I've been trying to deal with saving matrix fields to an external API by hooking onto the `craft()->on('entries.saveEntry)` function in a custom plugin I made. Matrices are nice for content authoring, but aren't quite nice for efficient retrieval in their current craft implementation.

Lets say I made a matrix field like this:

[image: matrix block]

And I wanted to handle parsing this using the `craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {}` hook inside of a plugin

```
foreach ($event->params['entry']->getFieldLayout()->getFields() as $fieldLayoutField)
{
    $imageArray = array();
    $field = $fieldLayoutField->getField();
    // Now get the prepped field value
    $value = $event->params['entry']->getFieldValue($field->handle);
    //Check what type of field that is being saved
    if(is_object($value)) {
          switch (get_class($value)) {
            case 'Craft\ElementCriteriaModel':
                $matrixBlocks = $value;
                $value = array();
                $elementType = $matrixBlocks->getElementType();
                if(is_object($elementType)) {
                    switch(get_class($elementType)) {
                        case 'Craft\MatrixBlockElementType':
                            //Get each element block
                            foreach($matrixBlocks as $blocks) {
                                $valueNested = array();
                                $valueNested['type'] = $blocks->type->handle;
                                $valueNested['status'] = $blocks->status;
                                //Loop over each field in the matrix field
                                foreach ($blocks->getContent()->getAttributes() as $key => $blockVal) 
                                {
                                    //How do I get the type of this element???
                                    //This could be an asset, or text field, etc.
                                    $valueNested[$key] = $blockVal;
                                }//End Foreach blocks->getContent()
                                //Add the results to the value array, since we can have multiple matrix types
                                array_push($value, $valueNested);
                            } // End For-each matrix blocks
                         break;
                    } //End switch
    } //End if object($value)
} // End For Each
```

This code works to save the matrix items into an array along with the value. I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to figure out what type the element inside of the matrix is programmatically?

Ex. Figure out if the item is a text field or a asset, etc?

I've spent hours in xdebug trying functions, looking through the matrix block type reference and seem quite lost. Anyone have any ideas?